# Writing to new local file from javascript MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, viewmodel

I have a dropdown meny in a shared layout that have one option that is called "mail me". 
Once the "mail me" is pressed, a pop-up modal comes up which can be filled with mail, number and message.

PROBLEM/CHALLENGE: Nothing (viewModel) seems to get passed from my the javascript on the shared layout .cshtml to the back-end. I would like to first of have my values passed to the controller correctly so I can write the info to a file which I then can review and contact whoever filled in the box.

Modal code `

```
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Kontakt</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="telefonnummer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> Telefonnummer</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="telefonnummer" placeholder="Ange telefonnummer">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Ange email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="meddelande"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Meddelande</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" style="height:50px" id="meddelande" placeholder="Ange meddelande">
                    </div>                      
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block" onclick="SkickaMail()">
                        Skicka
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Avbryt
                </button>
                @*<p>Need <a href="#">help?</a></p>*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

"SkickaMail" is supposed to call the Javascript and send a viewModel.
It's suppose to send the val:s to the controller page PeopleController and the IactionResult Kontakt but nothing gets passed to the controller, the vals are null when I debug in the controller. 
 Code below

```
<script>
//DEN HÄR DELEN FUNKAR INTE, VÄRDENA SKICKAS INTE KORREKT TILL CONTROLLERN AV NÅGON ANLEDNING.
    function SkickaMail() {

        var dataX = {
            //.val()metoden nedan är jQuery
            "@nameof(MVCrepetition.Models.ViewModels.Mail.TelNummer)": $("#@nameof(Model.TelNummer)").val(),
            "@nameof(MVCrepetition.Models.ViewModels.Mail.EMail)": $("#@nameof(Model.EMail)").val(),
            "@nameof(MVCrepetition.Models.ViewModels.Mail.Meddelande)": $("#@nameof(Model.Meddelande)").val()
        }


        $.post("/Kontakt", dataX, function (json) {

            })

        }
</script>
```

Controller code:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Kontakt(Mail viewModel)
    {
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.TelNummer = viewModel.TelNummer;
        mail.EMail = viewModel.EMail;
        mail.Meddelande = viewModel.Meddelande;

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\LiveTradingProject\mailfromcontact.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mail));

        //using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(@"c:\movie.json"))
        //    {
        //       JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        //       serializer.Serialize(file, movie);
        //    }

        return null;
    }
```

I hit the breakpoint on server side but the viewModels values are all null
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLlUX.png)

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough information.  Where's the rest of the code? We need to see the controller as well.  Edit:  There's a copy/paste error in the second snippet.

Comment: I think you should do `onclick="return SkickaMail()"` and have a `return false` at the end of your js function.

Comment: The name-value pairs in dataX look very strange.  What are you trying to achieve there?  I'm not familiar with all that syntax with the @ and #...  nameof looks like a server-side method... Are you expecting those strings to get evaluated server-side?  We need to see what you do with those strings on the server.

Comment: @Shyju  You're probably right - I also would like to see something other than an empty method in the success callback, but I don't think it's the cause of his problem - from the description, it sounds like he is able to successfully hit a breakpoint on the server, but dataX is empty.

Comment: His code is fine (to build the object). Simply add a `console.log(dataX)` and you can see the obj.

Comment: @Shyju Sure, maybe it's okay on client side, but he says he can't see any data in the object when he sets breakpoint on server.  I think we need to see his server code.

Comment: Updated with more information, the controller and also how it looks on serverside when I hit the breakpoint, the viewmodel (dataX) is empty/null.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't used ID properly in my Modal, that was the issue. The Id's now match the val:s and it works.